# Java RESTful Webservice CRUD Opreation Using Netbeans IDE

Tags: java, rest, netbeans

I'm working on RESTful Webservice in Java Using Database. By using RESTful Webservice from Database option in Netbeans it generates some Classes by that we are able to expose service like count,{id},{from}/{id}.

How do we write program to Insert,Delete and Update in Netbeans using Java.

This is my working environment.[image]

Comment: There are so many tutorials on this if you google "REST CRUD netbeans" example http://www.madebyjohann.com/index.php/college/learn-how/57-crud-in-a-restful-api-with-netbeans

Comment: @ring bearer I visited so many sites they designed sample Helloword program using RESTful Webservice or they showed basic code i.e, generate by IDE but not CRUD operation.

Comment: @ring bearer I followed this link http://www.oracle.com/webfolder/technetwork/tutorials/obe/java/RESTfulWebServices/RESTfulWebservices.htm#t2  which  describes sample database connection and auto generate code from RESTful Webservice from Database option from Netbeans

Comment: Try this below specified URL, with in that you can find how to create RestFul webservice and to consume. Hope it would be use full http://crunchify.com/how-to-build-restful-service-with-java-using-jax-rs-and-jersey/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Insertion Code like follows:

```
@POST
@Path("insertion")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String register(@FormParam("passhash") String passhash, @FormParam("email") String email,@FormParam("$pswdhash") String pwd, @FormParam("phno") String phno) {
    try {
        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test", "app", "app");
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert  into  MMX_REGISTRATION(name,email,pswd,phno) values(?,?,?,?)");
        pst.setString(1, passhash);
        pst.setString(2, email);
        pst.setString(3, pwd);
        pst.setString(4, phno);
        int result = pst.executeUpdate();
        System.out.println(result);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "success";
    //return "listform.html";
}
```

Retrieving Data as follows:

```
@Context private HttpServletRequest request; 
@GET
@Path("session")
@Produces(MediaType.TEXT_HTML)
@Consumes(MediaType.APPLICATION_FORM_URLENCODED)
public String session(@QueryParam("lname") String name1) {
    String response2 = null;
   //String name11 = "praveen";

     //String a[] = null;

    try {

        Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
        Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test", "app", "app");
        //PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("insert  into  restdb_insertion(id,company) values(?,?)");
        //String str1="select * from restdb_insertion where registration=?";
        PreparedStatement pst = con.prepareStatement("select * from MMX_REGISTRATION where name='"+name1+"'");
        System.out.println("select * from MMX_REGISTRATION where name='"+name1+"'");

        ResultSet rs = pst.executeQuery();
        ResultSetMetaData rsmd = rs.getMetaData();
        int cols = rsmd.getColumnCount();


        while (rs.next()) {
            if(!"null".equals(rs.getString(1))){
                 request.getSession(true);
                 HttpSession session = request.getSession();    
                 session.setAttribute("name","value");
                 session.setAttribute("UserName", rs.getString(2));
                 String username = (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
                 System.out.println(username);
               //  System.out.println(name);
                 //request.getSession(false);
                 //request.getSession().invalidate();
                 //String user = (String)session.getAttribute("UserName");
                 //System.out.println(user);
                return "success"+" "+username;
            }
        }

       //response = name1;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return "fail";

    //"<rss version='2.0'><channel><id>" + id + "</id><cmp>" +response.toArray()[0] + "</cmp></channel></rss>"
}
```

Comment: This question is usefull

Comment: try to keep the DB interaction  on a different layer.....this is very tightly coupled

Comment: **AbstractFacade** does have all those methods. You are complicating yourself, and this is not good practise. What are you going to do if you have x number of entities ?

Answer (score 3):

Maybe you should take a look on Spring-Data... You just have a Maven import, an interface with all the methods you need and it will use the name of your methods to make requests...

Here's an example : http://spring.io/guides/gs/accessing-data-rest/

Answer (score 2):

Separate your work into two layers DAO and service

- Inside DAO: Keep all the database interactions
- Inside Service: Keep only your webservice

Inject the dependency of your DAO implementation into your web service layer and invoke your CRUD operations(this is EJB concept ,you can also try Spring)

Answer (score 2):

You should define all your CRUD operations in a restful class. In each method of restful class you should call a service interface method which  has another class which has the implementation i.e ServiceImpl. Each method of your service Impl should interact with Dao layer for CRUD operations. 
You should avoid loading the driver class again and again for each CRUD operation and you should define it in a separate method/static block like this:-

```
static Connection con;
static{
 try {
    Class.forName("org.apache.derby.jdbc.ClientDriver");
    con = DriverManager.getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost:1527/test", "app", "app");
} catch (ClassNotFoundException | SQLException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}
 }
```